# Webcams not detected

Tags: webcam

I've installed ubuntu last version and have problem with webcam, it's invisible for computer, all usb ports are active, but webcam seems to be dead. Tried 2 creative cams, no one of these were working. Getting message "webcams not detected"...any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: post output of lsusb command (perhaps on pastebin or something)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing  **[cheese [image: software_center_icon]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cheese)**? Cheese is a software that allows you to take photos and videos with your webcam, with fun graphical effects. 
*Run the following to install the package via a terminal (Default keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>)*

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cheese
```

Comment: This answer could be a lot more helpful if you mentioned what cheese was and how it might help :)

Comment: instead of downvoting and commenting on other answers,u can help OTHERS.

Comment: sum, if you look on the review page and search for low quality posts, your name shows up a lot. Now, that tool isn't perfect, but short, error-filled posts aren't all that helpful. Instead of complaining, please try to write high-quality answers that will be more helpful.

Comment: again, instead of caring for my low quality post ,try to answer the person in need,don't waste your time.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you (I never do so anonymously). But let me explain how this site works: Voting (including downvoting) is one of the central features on this site. Other features include commenting and editing. The goal is to do what it takes to have high-quality answers, and simply adding another answer isn't always the best way to accomplish that. I'm trying to be helpful here; otherwise I'd just downvote and ignore you. I suggest that you read the FAQ: http://askubuntu.com/faq

Comment: let me tell you something, i can't comment due to my repu and i wanted to help that guy + so i was not left with any other option but to pOst it as answer..I was trying to be helpful to the OP.

Comment: @sum2000: Please do not get so offended. We really appreciate your contribution to this community but all Caesium and Scott are saying is, please provide more information about a package if you would think it is a solution. People are more open to downloading something knowing what it's going to do and not just downloading and installing something without knowing what that software might be. And -1 is just something that helps us in learning to answer the right way. Everyone gets -1's when they start and even when they have good rep, so please do not be so offended by it.

Answer (score 1):

if you haven't tried this yet... make sure you put your USB web cam into a POWERED USB port not just some dumb usb hub device.   It may not have enough power to work??

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/877768).